# Parsing complex string

Tags: php

The problem:

User send a string through an html field and ask the system to retrive rows 
from database.

The string is a partial or complete representation of a full datetime.

The complete format would be "yyyy-mm-ddThh:ii:ss.ss+hh:ii"

but User can also send a partial format "yyyy-dd", "mm-dd", "hh" and so on..

I need to build a process that translate the user input in the concrete representation.

I've take a look on Builder pattern to programmaticaly build all the parts of the datetime.

I also look at Interpreter pattern for parsing the user input an tell the builder what part is needed.

Questions:

could this be the right way?

how can I parse an undefined string (with a wide range of combination) into a concrete class representation?

A simplified bit of code:

```
class Director {
 $interpreter;
 $builder;

 public function __construct( $interpreter, $builder ) {
  $this->interpreter = $interpreter;
  $this->builder = $builder;
 }

 public function buildFromString( $format ) {
  $this->interpreter->parse( $format );
 }
}

class Interpreter {

 public function parse( $format ) {
  //a good solution to parse the undefined input string
 }
}
```

Thanks

------------------- added
because this process can lead to a wide range of misanderstanding, if a user enter "10" the UI ask user to define if he want the "year 10", "month 10" or "minute 10" but this is out of the question.

Comment: What options are there to get any indiction from the source as to what the string contains (such as if it's a date or a time). Use Regex overall, though.

Comment: you hit the problem! user can insert only a number (like 2016) or a combination of value (12-22) and also a with different separator (12/22). This is beacuse I'm thinking of a grammar with an interpreter but can't disect the user input..

Comment: Then what is to stop the user inputting the wrong date/time values anyway, the question is far too wide to realistically be efficient as is. **force** the user to at least indicate their type of data they enter. Also look up PHP [strtotime function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) which has some useful reading on the subject of syntax error handling in these situations

Comment: I can ask user to define what type of data is he sending when there could be misunderstood. But I want to mantain the input field a simple text-field

Comment: mmmh, maybe the php function sscanf() can help using a lot of templates

Comment: I'm going to build a Syntax analizer for my problem.

Comment: Well good luck with it, I hope you find a clean solution :-)